# Can't use injected class in Razor Pages code-behind class

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages

I have a simple page which just shows the list of movies. I injected `DbContext` into my page:

**List.cshtml**

```
@inject MovieContext Db
```

and try to use it in code-behind class:

**List.cshtml.cs**

```cs
public class ListModel : PageModel
{
    public IList<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Movies = await Db.Movies.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

However, I get the error:

> The name 'Db' does not exist in the current context

I have also tried to inject the context with `[Inject]` attribute, but this didn't work either:

```cs
public class ListModel : PageModel
{
    public IList<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    // Inject context
    [Inject] public MovieContext Db { get;set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Movies = await Db.Movies.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to use dependency injection directly in the code-behind class, as shown below.

```
public class ListModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly MovieContext _context;
        public ListModel(MovieContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public IList<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Movies = await _context.Movies.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

For more details,you can see the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Well, _you only need_ is not an answer. You didn't tell why `[Inject]` doesn't work.

Comment: Moreover, if I use `@inject` directive _on the page_, I still don't see this injected variable in my code-behind class (the beginning of my question).

Comment: If you use the @inject directive in the page, then you can only use the variable on the page. It has nothing to do with the code-behind class.[See the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0), If you want to inject the variable in the code-behind class, you need to use constructor dependency injection in the code-behind class ,[See the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Now I see. The strange thing is that I can use `[Inject]` in Blazor.

Comment: @JohnyL The `InjectAttribute` belongs to Blazor. It is in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components` namespace, which is basically Blazor. It has no place in Razor Pages.

Comment: @MikeBrind Thanks for clarification! 